# How to extract information from a data frame column to make a new data frame

Tags: r, format, strptime

I have a data frame and the first column, Raw Data, reads like this:

```
Raw Data
USGS    162        1994-10-15      14      A
USGS    162        1994-10-16      49      A
USGS    162        1994-10-17      39      A
......
```

I'm trying to make a new data frame that now has two columns instead of 1. The first column would have date and the second would have the integer values so it would look like this:

```
Date        Integer
1994-10-15  14
```

I know you can use strptime() and format() to extract year, month, day but I'm not sure how this works when you have extra numbers and characters in the cell. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the language that you are using and some code that would inform the data structures involved.

Based on the phrase data frame I would guess R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `read.table`.

```
 res <- read.table(text=df$RawData, header=FALSE, sep='', 
   colClasses=c(NA, NA, 'Date', 'integer'), col.names=c('', '', 
            'Date', 'Integer', ''))[3:4]
 res
 #        Date Integer
 #1 1994-10-15      14
 #2 1994-10-16      49
 #3 1994-10-17      39
```

Or using `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`.  The 'Date' column class can be changed to 'Date' afterwards with `as.Date`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 setnames(cSplit(df, 'RawData', sep=' ', type.convert=TRUE)[,3:4,
              with=FALSE], c('Date', 'Integer'))[]
```

Or

```
 library(tidyr)
 extract(df, 'RawData', into= c('Date', 'Integer'), 
         '\\S*\\s*\\S*\\s*(\\S*)\\s*(\\S*).*', convert=TRUE)
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setnames(setDT(df)[, tstrsplit(RawData, ' +', 
            type.convert=TRUE)[3:4]], c('Date', 'Integer'))[]
```

NOTE: 'df' from @bgoldst's post

Comment: Dang, this is a better solution than mine! Only quibble is that your Date column is not of type Date. You can solve this using the `colClasses` argument to `read.table()`, perhaps `colClasses=c(NA,NA,'Date','integer')`. +1

Comment: Ah, and just remembered, you can also use the `col.names` argument of `read.table()` to set the column names, rather than `setNames()`. `read.table()` does everything!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
df <- data.frame(RawData=c('USGS    162        1994-10-15      14      A','USGS    162        1994-10-16      49      A','USGS    162        1994-10-17      39      A'), stringsAsFactors=F );
df;
##                                        RawData
## 1 USGS    162        1994-10-15      14      A
## 2 USGS    162        1994-10-16      49      A
## 3 USGS    162        1994-10-17      39      A
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df$RawData,'\\s+'), function(x) data.frame(Date=as.Date(x[3]), Integer=as.integer(x[4]) ) ) );
df2;
##         Date Integer
## 1 1994-10-15      14
## 2 1994-10-16      49
## 3 1994-10-17      39
```

Since your dates are already in YYYY-mm-dd format, there's actually no need for `strptime()` or `format()` or anything; you can coerce the string directly to Date type with `as.Date()`.

The only challenge is to extract the relevant pieces of text from the input strings that contain the date and integer values. I made the assumption that the input data is always whitespace-delimited, because it appears that way in your question. My solution splits the input strings into fields on whitespace usting `strsplit(df$RawData,'\\s+')`. This results in a list of character vectors. The `lapply()` call then iterates over each vector and extracts and coerces the two fields to Date and integer type, combined into a one-row data.frame. Finally, the `do.call(rbind, ... )` combines all such one-row data.frames into a single data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for fun with `gsub` (convert the column to integer with `as.integer` if needed):

```
x = unlist(df)

data.frame(
   Date = gsub(".*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}).*","\\1",x),
   Integer = gsub(".*(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})[ ]+(\\d+).*","\\2",x)
)

#               Date Integer
#RawData1 1994-10-15      14
#RawData2 1994-10-16      49
#RawData3 1994-10-17      39
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(RawData = c("USGS    162        1994-10-15      14      A", 
"USGS    162        1994-10-16      49      A", "USGS    162        1994-10-17      39      A"
)), .Names = "RawData", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```